# Prove that limit of sequence $2n^{2}-3n^{3}$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Please check my proof
Consider the upper bound and lower bound of seqeunce.

For every $n\leq k+1$ when n is natural number.

The upper bound is -5 when n=1

If n=k+1,the sequence will be$-3k^{3}-7k^{2}-5-1$,that is decreasing sequence with no lower bound.

Because it decreasing sequence with no lower bound,the limit of sequence does not exist.

Comment: How do you know it decreases with no lower bound?

Comment: Alternatively, one may write $2n^{2}-3n^{3}=-3n^3\left(1-\frac2{3n}\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to recall some basic concept.

**Definition.** A sequence $(a_n)$ is said to **diverge to negative infinity** if given any negative real number $K$, we can find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n>N$, we have $a_n<K$. In this case, we write
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=-\infty.$$

Going back to your question, we are going to show that 
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(2n^2-3n^3)=-\infty.$$

Let $K<0$. By using the Archimedean Property(assuming that you are familiar with), we can find a natural number $N$ for which $N>-K$. So, if $n>N$ then we get
\begin{align}
3n^3-2n^2&>3n^3-2n^3\\
&=n^3\\
&>N^3\\
&\geq N\\
&>-K.
\end{align}
Equivalently, this means that, if $n>N$ then
$$2n^2-3n^3<K.$$
Applying the definition that we had, it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(2n^2-3n^3)=-\infty.$$

Hope this help.